# Please help me to get out of this problem

Tags: apt, ppa, repository

Err:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/neizod/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release
  404  Not Found
Reading package lists... Done

E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/neizod/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.

N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.

N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The neizod ppa I found, supports **saucy** only. Not **xenial**. If you used:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:neizod/ppa`

to add that ppa, you should use

`sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:neizod/ppa`

to remove it since it's useless on Xenial.